# Is there a way to programmatically re-evaluate a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a Google Sheet Add-on and I have a script that copies a few sheets from a shared sheet (includes formulas and formatting). The script properly copies everything over, however the formulas return an error when it first loads. The formula is correct and I am able to eliminate the error simply by selecting the cell then pressing `enter` to move out of the cell.

In the image below, you can see that I have cleared the errors in Column C, all the other cells still have the error and are marked as such.

Is there a way to programmatically clear these errors? To be clear, the formula works but for some reason it throws an error to start. I tried `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` but that didn't do anything.

Thanks for helping!
EDIT - I tried `=iferror(original formula, value if error)` which gets rid of the error message, but it doesn't force the spreadsheet to evaluate the formula.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (Is your script inserting the Data Source sheet or renaming a sheet to Data Source? Is your script using `setValue` / `setValues` to add the formula or it's using `setFormula`/ `setFormulas`, if your formula including the `=` on the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the spreadsheet settings, you can have the sheet recalculate every minute. This is basically the same is clicking a cell and hitting enter. See screenshots below.

Alternatively, I think you could probably just simulate your enter actions by doing this...?

```
function updateFormulas() {
  // ss is your sheet
  var theRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var someFormulas = theRange.getFormulas();
  theRange.setFormulas(someFormulas);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the screenshot shows that only works for NOW, TODAY, RAND and RANDBETWEEN

Comment: I'm not sure that's true @Rubén, though I do see that language. I am reasonably certain I've seen spreadsheets update `Query` data within the google environment more frequently with this setting. I included a differnt option that's not very elegant.

Comment: Was you able to reproduce the OP issue and confirm that the solution that you are proposing solve it?

Comment: @pgSystemTester - your `updateFormulas()` solution worked. I'm able to just call the function on sheet creation, so not ideal but it'll work. Thanks, I've marked it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Craig.Pearce. So the refresh every minute didn't work? What if you just update a single cell with a formula, or even just a clear contents? Anyway, I agree it's clunky. I suspect if you had everything on the same tab, you wouldn't have this issue. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't try the refresh every minute. Since I'm intending to deploy as an add-on, I don't want to rely on a feature that is documented to not work on formulas other than NOW, TODAY, RAND, RANDBETWEEN. I think the issue is that I have a bunch of sheets in my account. A script that the user would execute copies the sheets, including the formulas to their own spreadsheet. For whatever reason it doesn't evaluate the formulas automatically.

Comment: Oh... yeah I should have noted that you're building an add-on. I'll leave my screenshots in there as it might match someone searching for something similar. Anyway, thanks for the feedback and hope it's a success.